# Hosting a static website on Google App Engine using a PHP form

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I am hosting a simple HTML / CSS static website, that contains a `php` contact form, on Google App Engine. However, when the `php` Contact form is completed and submitted an error is generated, as it is not being run on the host. If I select the form directly it simply downloads, see https://firebellycomputing.com/forms/contact.php

Can anyone suggest a solution please?

My app.yaml is:

```
runtime: php72

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: spaqwebsite28apr2021/MyPortfolio-pro/index.html
  upload: spaqwebsite28apr2021/MyPortfolio-pro/index.html

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: spaqwebsite28apr2021/MyPortfolio-pro/\1
  upload: spaqwebsite28apr2021/MyPortfolio-pro/(.*)
```

Comment: Hello, Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please include your `app.yaml` in your question for us to check how you configure and deploy your application in App Engine.

Comment: Hi John,

My app.yaml is:

runtime: php72

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: spaqwebsite28apr2021/MyPortfolio-pro/index.html
  upload: spaqwebsite28apr2021/MyPortfolio-pro/index.html

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: spaqwebsite28apr2021/MyPortfolio-pro/\1
  upload: spaqwebsite28apr2021/MyPortfolio-pro/(.*)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your `app.yaml` you only serve static files for your application. Add `script` in `handlers` that will serve your all `PHP` files or specific PHP `file`, see the example below:

```
runtime: php55 
api_version: 1 
threadsafe: true

# Serve all php scripts from the root.
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1
```

or

```
runtime: php55 
api_version: 1 
threadsafe: true

# Serve specific php scripts
- url: /contact.php
  script: form_folder/contact.php
  upload: form_folder/contact.php
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I've tried both options and both still yield the same result i.e. the php form is downloaded, rather than executed on the host.
When I try with runtime: php72 it complains of the upload: attribute being present and that script: should be set to auto. Help!

Comment: You should use this config in runtime php55, if you are using php72 you need to use a front controller that will handle the app request.

Comment: My app.yaml is:

runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: spaqwebsite28apr2021/MyPortfolio-pro/index.html
  upload: spaqwebsite28apr2021/MyPortfolio-pro/index.html

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: spaqwebsite28apr2021/MyPortfolio-pro/\1
  upload: spaqwebsite28apr2021/MyPortfolio-pro/(.*)

# Serve all php scripts from the root.
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1 

But I still get the error where it downloads the php form rather than execute it i.e.
Error: ajax = true; $contact->to = $receiving_email_address; $contact->from_name = ........

Comment: @user1872945 it seems the issue is not from the App Engine, can you include the reproducible codes in your question from contact form(html) to your contact.php? Have you tried if your apps is working on your local host?

Comment: Contact.html can be found at https://firebellycomputing.com/contact.html

Comment: Contact.html can be found at https://firebellycomputing.com/contact.html
and the associated php form https://firebellycomputing.com/forms/contact.php
When I try locally I get the following error:
TypeError: Failed to fetch

Comment: Hi John
Can you please explain what you mean by "can you include the reproducible codes in your question from contact form(html) to your contact.php"

Comment: Did you purchase this website template? I can't replicate this issue since the emailer/API/Library of this template is paid.

Comment: Hi John,
Yes I did purchase this library from BootStrapMade. It's over 6,604 lines long.